# Highcharts and phantomjs error. Can't find variable Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, phantomjs

I am trying to generate some serverside charts using **Highcharts** and **phantomjs**, but the following error keeps appearing:

> Can't find variable Highcharts.

I know that there are similar questions here but none of them have helped me.
I am using Windows, with phantomjs 2.1.1, Highcharts 4.2.5

[image: error image]

Here is the options.js file:

```
{
  infile: {
            xAxis: {
                        categories:['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr',
                                    'May','Jun','Jul','Aug',
                                    'Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
                },
            series:[
                {
                    data:[29.9,71.5,106.4,129.2,
                          144.0,176.0,135.6,148.5,
                          216.4,194.1,95.6,54.4]
                }]
          },
          callback: function(chart){
          chart.renderer
               .arc(200,150,100,50,-Math.PI,0)
               .attr({fill:'#FCFFC5',stroke:'black','stroke-width':1})
               .add();
          },
 constr: "Chart",
 outfile: "//tmp//chart.png"
}
```

And the highcharts-convert.js config options:

```
var config = {
        HIGHCHARTS: 'highcharts.js',
        JQUERY: 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
        TIMEOUT: 5000 /* 5 seconds timout for loading images */
    },
```

Has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: So here's the obvious question! Have you included highcharts library?

Comment: Following these instructions:

Save these files all to one location; highcharts-convert.js, highcharts.js or highstock.js for stock charts, highcharts-more.js (for bubble, range, polar charts) and last but not least jQuery. The dependency and location of these files is configured in the highcharts-convert.js script. 

I have added the dependency in highcharts-convert.js as shown above.

Comment: Attach a screenshot with list all files in the folder: pha-high

Comment: The solution provided from @Max Uppenkamp works! With the 'resources' attribute the chart is being rendered just fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the exact same problem, although my command looks a bit different:

```
phantomjs  highcharts-convert.js -infile delete_this.json -outfile /home/max/BLA.png -width 300 -constr Chart -resources highcharts.js,jquery.js
```

as you see i included the needed files using the -resources option of phantom js, but i still get the 'Can't find variable: Highcharts' Error.

Maybe the resources part helps you?

EDIT: I solved my issue, and yours as well i think.

If you use the command like i described it, it doesn't give you the Highcharts error, BUT it breaks when trying to parse the resources. That is due to a grave error in the current version of the highcharts-convert.js script.

In line 682 they split the arguments, but they use an undefined parameter resources.

```
fileList = resources.split('\,');
```

You need to change that to:

```
fileList = params.resources.split('\,');
```

It works for me now, i hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the solution @max-uppenkamp.  The Highcharts team should integrate this into their code without delay!  EDIT: I see you have already notified them:  https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server/issues/18

I note that a command-line as minimal as this will still work:

`phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options.json -outfile chart.png -resources highcharts.js`

Also, I only need `highcharts.js`, `highcharts-convert.js` and `options.js` in my folder.  Seems that I don't need highcharts-more or jquery.

NB. My options.json file looks like this:

`{
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
}`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution number 2**

Create a file called `resources.js` with the following contents and place it in the same folder as `options.js`.  Now you don't need to edit `highcharts-convert.js` and it will still work.

```
{
    "files": "highcharts.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this might help others. If you're using https for jsfiddle.net then make sure you're including the highcharts library with https too. Otherwise you would get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts" in Safari console(not very helpful). In chrome console, you get a clear message. "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

For https make sure you have the following in the html window of jsfiddle:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could also try <script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>